# cool untitled sequence thingy

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence

Let's define **f<sub>n</sub>(k)** as the sum of the first **k** terms of the natural numbers **[1, ∞)** where each number is repeated **n** times.

```
k       | 0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
--------+-------------------------------------------------
f_1(k)  | 0    1    3    6    10   15   21   28   36   45
deltas  |   +1   +2   +3   +4   +5   +6   +7   +8   +9
--------+-------------------------------------------------
f_2(k)  | 0    1    2    4    6    9    12   16   20   25
deltas  |   +1   +1   +2   +2   +3   +3   +4   +4   +5
--------+-------------------------------------------------
f_3(k)  | 0    1    2    3    5    7    9    12   15   18
deltas  |   +1   +1   +1   +2   +2   +2   +3   +3   +3
```

The anti-diagonals of this as a square array is similar to [OEIS sequence A134546](https://oeis.org/A134546).

### Challenge

Write a **program/function** that takes **two non-negative integers n and k** and outputs **f<sub>n</sub>(k)**.

#### Specifications

- [Standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) **apply**.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are **forbidden**.
- Your solution **can either be 0-indexed or 1-indexed for n and/or k** but please specify which.
- This challenge is not about finding the shortest approach in all languages, rather, it is about finding the **shortest approach in each language**.
- Your code will be **scored in bytes**, usually in the encoding UTF-8, unless specified otherwise.
- Built-in functions that compute this sequence are **allowed** but including a solution that doesn't rely on a built-in is encouraged.
- Explanations, even for "practical" languages, are **encouraged**.

#### Test cases

In these test cases, **n** is 1-indexed and **k** is 0-indexed.

```
n   k      fn(k)

1   2      3
2   11     36
11  14     17
14  21     28
21  24     27
24  31     38
31  0      0
```

In a few better formats:

```
1 2
2 11
11 14
14 21
21 24
24 31
31 0

1, 2
2, 11
11, 14
14, 21
21, 24
24, 31
31, 0
```

#### Reference implementation

This is written in [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/).

```hs
f n k = sum $ take k $ replicate n =<< [1..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZAxbsMwDEV3n@IPWQo0BuR6TE5SdGBtqhZsyYFEI1foKXK4XMSl46QoBLjt30S@/ymyo9TzMMyzRUCPI9LksYNQz/rcIfJpcA0Ja/t4OODVlOXbvN/jwf9PLVsXGAQ7hUbcGNQvHcltUIKcR1D8mDwHSRpMoUVf6JSH1l/9pYUabVmWP62rvhfakHQM62IShYSjT1tBm7pdZg0KJFOkAWHy7xyTtp5x/bw8/R6Yn/quc8eRwdR09zy4tLCsZKuoOM@pKDw5taEdi8V0ii6IbmthUGWVCsbkkIGp81qNKucqTcu5qsaLmb8A)

[This challenge was sandboxed.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14260/)

Comment: Do you think that my edit improves formatting, or is it just on my browser?

Comment: @user202729 Heh... it looks off on my browser but I doubt my formatting looked good on most browsers... I'll just keep it like that, it doesn't lose any meaning. Just looks weird. :P

Comment: Do we need to handle the case `f_n(0) = 0` for `k` 0-indexed?

Comment: @Cinaski **0** must be the first term, yes.

Comment: "_cool untitled sequence thingy_" Lol, I'm not the only one having a hard time coming up with names for sequences I made up I see.. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I was thinking of something along the lines of "Element-wise repeated range sum", but then I realized I literally suck at naming and my current title is so much cooler. :P

Comment: Can we output the first k elements?

Comment: @dylnan Sorry, no. In my opinion, that makes comparing solutions harder.

Comment: Isn't this just a long-winded way to say "n times the sum of natural numbers up to k", which is equal to `n*(k²+k)/2`?

Comment: @Fabian No, you only sum the first `k` terms from the list of repeated natural numbers, not the first `n*k` terms.

Comment: Ah, ok. Still seems like it could be optimised, but that would probably not make the code shorter.

Answer (score 13):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>32 28</s> 23 bytes

```ruby
->n,k{k.step(0,-n).sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYkxDoQgFAV7T0GHax7E/6VdL0J@oYk2RkMWKTbq2RGqmcn80vzP6zeb8cB2bTaeS2h7mONjY9qf7D2BBZ5BVEAEcpUOXJvLrc0OA4nYfQrXPWG@m5DOqHxRaDNqqLW6SKeVbp78Ag)

#### Explanation

Let's visualize the sum as the area of a triangle, for example with n=3 and k=10:

```ruby
*
*
*
**
**
**
***
***
***
****
```

Then we sum by column instead of row: the first column is `k`, then `k-n`, `k-2n` and so on.

Answer (score 8):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
Σ↑ṘN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9ziR20TH@6c4ff//38jk//GhgA)

#### Explanation

This just ends up being a direct translation of the reference implementation in the challenge:

```
   N  Start from the infinite sequence of all natural numbers.
  Ṙ   Replicate each element n times.
 ↑    Take the first k values.
Σ     Sum them.
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>34</s> 28 bytes

```python
lambda n,k:(k+k%n)*(k/n+1)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYvBCoMwEER/JRcx0Smya05C@yNpDoqIknYN4qVfn2ZPM483k3/3fgqX7fkun/m7rLMRpMmmPjXiOpsG6ckNdXBeaswhJgQCRwQGUQ0ikNf0YGWuVpk9Ropxytcht37RPl4tNlurK38)

Thanks Martin Ender, Neil and Mr Xcoder for helping.

Comment: You don't actually need the `k/n` anyway - `k-(k/n)*n` is just `k%n`. See my Batch answer.

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYvBCoMwEER/JZdi0o7IrjkJ@iNpDpYiStpVxIsXfz1mTzOPN7Odx7wK56l/59/4/3xHI0idTa/0EPesL5sacU0ZrLsas4gJgcARgUFUggjkNT1YmYtVZo@WYuy2fZFDv6jqocJkS3X5Bg)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think it could get so simple.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 40 bytes

```
Tr@Sort[Join@@Range@#2~Table~#][[;;#2]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6TIITi/qCTaKz8zz8EhKDEvPdVB2aguJDEpJ7VOOTY62tpa2Sg2Vu1/QFFmXolDWrSRiY6xYex/AA)

```
Tr[Range@(s=⌊#2/#⌋)]#+#2~Mod~#(s+1)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6QoOigxLz3VQaPY9lFPl7KRvvKjnm7NWGVtZaM63/yUOmWNYm1DTbX/AUWZeSUOadFGJjrGhrH/AQ)

## Mathematica, 18 bytes

**by Martin Ender**

```
Tr@Range[#2,0,-#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6TIISgxLz01WtlIx0BHVzlW7X9AUWZeiUNatJGJjrFh7H8A)

```
n~Sum~{n,#2,0,-#}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P68uuDS3rjpPR9lIx0BHV7lW7X9AUWZeiUNatKGOUex/AA)

Comment: `Tr@Range[#2,0,-#]&` or `n~Sum~{n,#2,0,-#}&` using the trick from G B's Ruby answer.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>12</s> <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```apl
+/∘⌈÷⍨∘⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRt/UcdMx71dBze/qh3BYjZu/n/fw0gaWigqQDk66UpGOiAuQA)

`n` on the left, `k` (0 indexed) on the right.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
:iY"Ys0h1G)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yozUimy2CDD0F3z/39DQy4jAA)

`k` is 0-indexed.
Takes input in reverse order.

Saved 1 byte thanks to @Giuseppe

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Rxḣ³S
```

One more byte than @Mr.Xcoder's Jelly solution but this is my first ever submission in Jelly and I'm still confused about how the tacitness of Jelly chooses operands so I'm still satisfied. Note the order of the inputs are `k` then `n`.

**Explanation**

```
Rxḣ³S
R           Range: [1,2,...,k]
 x          Times: repeat each element n times: [1,1,1,2,2,2,...,n,n,n]
  ḣ³        Head: take the first k elements. ³ returns the first argument.
    S       Sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z@o4uGOxYc2B////9/Q5L@hIQA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

**1-indexed**

```
Ḷ:‘S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm1WjxpmBP///9/Q8L8RAA) or see a [test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm1WjxpmBP@PjjbUMYrViTbSMTQEUoaGOoYmINpExwjENwLKgvhGJjrGhrGxoYfb9XVUHjWtcQPiUPf/AA).

Comment: You can do 0 indexing so I think `Ḷ:S` also works

Comment: @dylnan Actually I don’t think that’s what 0-indexed means here. I rolled back, and we’ll see

Comment: @dylnan Division by zero is an error.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>24</s>  21 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(n)(k)`. Returns [`false` instead of `0`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9064/should-booleans-be-allowed-where-a-number-is-required/9067#9067).

```js
n=>g=k=>k>0&&k+g(k-n)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

n=>g=k=>k>0&&k+g(k-n)

console.log(f(1 )(2 )) // 3
console.log(f(2 )(11)) // 36
console.log(f(11)(14)) // 17
console.log(f(14)(21)) // 28
console.log(f(21)(24)) // 27
console.log(f(24)(31)) // 38
```

#### How?

```js
n =>             // main unamed function taking n
  g = k =>       // g = recursive function taking k
    k > 0 &&     // if k is strictly positive:
      k +        //   add k to the final result
      g(k - n)   //   subtract n from k and do a recursive call
```

This is similar to [@GB's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149355/58563).

The challenge describes how to build the 'staircase' from left to right, whereas this recursive function builds it from bottom to top. With **n = 2** and **k = 11**:

[image: staircase]

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>38</s> 34 bytes

Recursive definition.

*-4 bytes thanks to [Steadybox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61405/steadybox).*

```c
f(n,k){return k--?1+f(n,k)+k/n:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcpBCsIwEIXhdXOKISDMMCk2bgRT8SwSjaTBWGK6Kj17HHHh6oP/Pd8/vG8tYDaJ1nKvS8mQ@v5i@dc47fNpcFuLucLzGjOSWlUXXgXwmyY4g3XCCEeB2cC81DdqTaS6/y/Kb3DCCPYgMhPMRZaAencDbSDgZCASObW1Dw)

---

**32 bytes by [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder), [G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18535/g-b)**

```c
f(n,k){return(k+k%n)*(k/n+1)/2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcpBCsIwEIXhdXOKIVCYcSI13XSRehiJRtLgWGK6Kj17jCtXH7z3@/PT@1oDikm050fZsmDi1AudMA3ClobRHTVKgdctCpLaVRfeGfA3LXAF6xozTA1mA@tWPqg1ker@XWzdxTVmsGOTmWDN7Qmo@ztoAwEXA5HIqaN@AQ)

Comment: [34 bytes in Python](https://tio.run/##TcgxCoAgGAbQvVN8W0pK2BIIHcYwS62/kJYWr24FDY3vHde57NSV4obVbKM1IBF1hCErs2MPpOJNlrGl4vYED09IhuaJKYGe6wpvh193XONInk445kXgovpY1@UG), [36 bytes in C](https://tio.run/##RcpBCsIwEIXhdXOKISDMMAk2bgRT8SwSjaTBtMR0VerVY3Tj6oP/PacfztXqMalIa76XJSeIF8O/og3xW8d9OvV2qyEVeF5DQhKr6PyUAb9phDMY2xjg2GBWMC/lhVISie7/C@3X28YA5tBkJphzWzzK3Q2kAo@jgkBkxVY/)

Comment: Using G B's approach, [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##RcpBCsIwEIXhdXOKIVCYMSm13XSRehiJRtLgWGK6KvXqcVy5@uC933cP72sNyDbRnu9ly4zJpJbp1H0w9Uz96I4aucDzGhlJ7aoJrwz4mxa4wOCEGSbBGAvrVt6oNZFq/l2U7uyEGYZRNIZgzfIE1O0NtIWAi4VI5NRRvw)

Comment: https://tio.run/##RcpBCoMwEIXhtTnFEBBmOik2brqIHkZSUmLoVKxdiWeP01VXH7z3x@szxloTiiu0y4iFSyt0wdIJe@r6cNQsG7ymLEhmN016r4C/aYYRfFAGuCvMDpbv9kFriUzz77J2t6AM4HuVmWBZ9Ulo2wdYBwlnB5komKOe -> 28 bytes

Comment: 34 bytes (the recursive version): `f(n,k){return k--?1+f(n,k)+k/n:0;}` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcpBCsIwEIXhdXOKISDMMCk2bgRT8SwSjaTBWGK6Kj17HHHh6oP/Pd8/vG8tYDaJ1nKvS8mQ@v5i@dc47fNpcFuLucLzGjOSWlUXXgXwmyY4g3XCCEeB2cC81DdqTaS6/y/Kb3DCCPYgMhPMRZaAencDbSDgZCASObW1Dw)

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 34 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/a(%2+%2%%%1)*(%2/%1+1)/2
```

A closed-form formula that I found. First argument `n` is 1-indexed, second argument `k` is 0-indexed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 29 bytes

```python
lambda n,k:sum(range(k,0,-n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBDoIwEEWv0h1t8kmcsSsSvUjtogSrBBlIwYWnr53V@y8vf/@d70245tujftI6TskIluH4rrYkeT3tggt6ca7mrWgys5gQCBwRGEQNRCCv9GB1blWdPa4U47CXWU79ouvvHbJt09U/)

Thanks to [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman) for -3 bytes!

---

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 30 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k:k>0and k+f(n,k-n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCoQwEAS/kpsrtuCMOQmbj4QcIhKU7I4iuezrsxlPRVF0X7@yn8K1pvcnftctGkFespuibCYP6dV0lL6m89ZiDjHeEzjAM4gaiEBWacHq3Ko6W8wUwnLdhxTdohtdh@exr38)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes

```hs
n#k|m<-k`mod`n=sum[m,m+n..k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P085uybXRjc7ITc/JSHPtrg0NzpXJ1c7T08vO/Z/bmJmnoKtQko@lwIQFBRl5pUoqCgYKigrGKGIGAFFDA1RFYFUGZqgipmAdKKqMwKbhqrOCKTO2PA/AA)

An approach I found just by screwing around with some range parameters. Most definitely not the shortest but it's pretty cool how there's so many different approaches.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>37</s> <s>33</s> 31 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to Giuseppe

```r
function(n,k)sum(rep(1:k,,k,n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jTydbs7g0V6MotUDD0CpbRydbJ09T839yYomGQpqGkY6hoaaOkoKtQlq8kQaQHZOnpKDJBZU1NtQxgMkaG2oYoMoamegYIzSbAFVD5P8DAA)

Nothing fancy. <s>The `[0:k]` handles the case when k=0.</s>

Comment: You can get rid of the braces here. If you use the in-order arguments for `rep.default`, you can get rid of `[0:k]` by using `rep(1:k,,k,n)` but then your answer is basically rturnbull's but with base R rather than `R + pryr`

Comment: You can still get rid of the braces! `{}`

Comment: the [0:k] substitution got me and I forgot about the braces :)

Answer (score 2):

## C++, 53 bytes

Just use the formula. `n` is 1-indexed and `k` is 0-indexed.

```cpp
[](int n,int k){return k/n*(k/n+1)/2*n+k%n*(k/n+1);};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3LDoIwFETX9ismMQZqMYgbFy3@iHHRlELK40KgXRG/HYsL3cyZm5zcMdN0aYzZdPAjapTb85U68qBsz46vs/VhJnQ5ndMYouD57UyiO/1u@Zbb0ZHpQ2Wh3Lj42erhwVhYHDUgPdhl0sZi8ZVkbP87aEcpZys71OOM72CLEoWMULhHCJHBjMFDKViqes4Of9dF9yojFIpbpBD8J9dpm8HxvSZIJHtvHw)

Comment: Save a couple of bytes by abusing the `~` operator. `[](int n,int k){return-k/n*~(k/n)/2*n-k%n*~(k/n);};`

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 13 bytes

```
1#.]{.(#1+i.)
```

How it works:

The left argument is n, the right is k.

`i.`  generates a list 0..k-1

`1+`  adds one to each number of the list, yealding 1,2,...,k

`#`   forms a hook with the above, so n copies of each elements of the list are copied.

`]{.`  take the first n of them

`1#.` find their sum by base conversion.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8N9QWS@2Wk9D2VA7U0/zvyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGvoKhQpqCEYRpBGQaGkKFQeKGJlCOCUgRVMYIrAMqYwSSMTb8DwA)

Comment: I like the hook.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>29</s> 26 bytes

```
\d+
$*
(?=.*?(1+)$)\1
$'
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYk5DoAwEAN7vyLFInKskLykRflICpCgoKFA/D8Eqpmx7@M5r60NfvV1T0HdD4ipsHWFRPiyTLF4piChEjKCrVGdwdSRYHdmMPeJsO/JsF4zXw) Link includes test cases and header to reformat them to its preferred input (0-indexed `k` first, 1-indexed `n` second). I was inspired by @GB's Ruby answer. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
(?=.*?(1+)$)\1
$'
```

Match every string of `n` within `k`, and replace the match with everything after the match. This is `k-n`, `k-2n`, `k-3n`, but `n` is also after the match, so you get `k`, `k-n`, `k-2n` etc. This also matches `n`, which is simply deleted (it's no longer needed).

```
1
```

Sum the results and convert back to decimal.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
s%_ES
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%25_ES&input=11%0A2&debug=0)**

Port of G B's Ruby answer. A port of my Jelly one would be 6 bytes: `+s/Rvz`

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 39 bytes

```perl6
->\n,\k{(0,{|($_+1 xx n)}...*)[^k].sum}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##NY5BT4NAEIXv8yveodpdoVsWDG1C2nj17k1so7BNGmAh3a3BIL/Mm38MWaiTTPK9vHkz06hLGQ9Xo/AZiyyh6gv3WZ0r7IbVPtV@WnQs8Ltvtjh6Em0LzXshxAN/PRRvwlyrfhgjT1YZix3Ks1aG8d8fkdXVB1unubd26lnbhNyRl3EuoaZ81/CmUEKn@nLLr/ZYHMEwnkVajK3aRmVW5eDoCDgbuNcYRr@ABwnu43/GhzhVli3vIrPk1A8SQIipInIg5SxiciQfJyU35CicvXBLjsLZCzfkKLrltuQomFcGfw)

***n*** and ***k*** are both 1 based

### Expanded:

```perl6
-> \n, \k { # pointy block lambda with two parameters ｢n｣ and ｢k｣

  ( # generate the sequence

    0,         # seed the sequence (this is why ｢k｣ is 1-based)

    {          # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣
      |(       # slip this into outer sequence
        $_ + 1 # the next number
        xx n   # repeated ｢n｣ times (this is why ｢n｣ is 1-based)
      )
    }

    ...        # keep doing that until

    *          # never stop

  )[ ^k ]      # get the first ｢k｣ values from the sequence
  .sum         # sum them
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 40 bytes

```
{n:Int,k:Int->Array(k,{i->i/n+1}).sum()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BCoMwEEX3nmIQFxk6tk10Ja3QZVct9ATZREJ0LFELRTx7qtLMYng8HnzXj63l8NEtmGuYubrzSG77eX3zXn@Fo9nmtT3xQS54HKZO4BLMxNBpy0L7ZqhgLy@v0VtuaoQ5gfVM70EIJodgGfSWPIx4auuFJIW0kyIp/yglyTJySSp6tdbRq5KK6AtJZ0SE97o6tizSjClzeZ3NZl9dUkyW8AM)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 23 bytes

```java
n->k->(k+k%n)*(k/n+1)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9La8MwEITv@RVLwCAntlMruaUx9FIopukh9FRCUf0I8kMW0jpgSn67u3ZciA9Cq@Gb0U4hrsJvdKaKtOxlrRuDUJAWtCirIG9VgrJRwWq/0O1PJRNIKmEtvAup4HcBYFEgqddGpoCZRSYVwtGD4YrdEQF4U/g6JT3T/KmE6T50ZgQ2JoL80Cs/Kv2IlevSUe6KlRu1Dt0N7/ejfcgymW0rhAPkgdC66tjRvQ8vlhJZ7N7RU2cxq4OmxUAb8uVsmX87KXNSl7xO6qilN6wXe1Pi6LvRmeo99qmpJDsh5Vy@ziDMxf4XGpuGHp9@HZ/cgzB8FMKQlN1M2XnAZwwnhs8YTsx2xmyJeZr2vPV/)

Port of [G B's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149365/16236).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
FL`}){I£O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fzSehVrPa89Bi////jbgMDQE)

**Explanation**

```
F           # n times do
 L`         # pop top of stack (initially k), push 1 ... topOfStack
   }        # end loop
    )       # wrap stack in a list
     {      # sort the list
      I£    # take the first k elements
        O   # sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k:sum(sorted(range(1,k+1)*n)[:k])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIU8n26q4NFejOL@oJDVFoygxLz1Vw1AnW9tQUytPM9oqO1bzf0FRZl6JQhpQ2EiTC8Yx0jE0RPAMDXUMTZC4JjpGSLJGQJ1IskYmOsaGmv8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 38 bytes

```python
lambda n,k:sum(i/n+1for i in range(k))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYuxDsIwEEN/JVsTYYTuyFQJfiRkCIJAVHqt0jLw9SE32X6219/@XoRbvtzaJ833RzKCady@sy0nOVBeqimmiKlJXk87OdcU9Y3CEAgcERhEXYhAXtWDNXNvNbPHmWIc11pk1y@G43VAtt269gc)

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 54 bytes

```
#(nth(reductions +(for[i(rest(range))j(range %)]i))%2)
```

2nd argument `k` is 0-indexed, so `(f 14 20)` is 28.

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 13 bytes

```
+/⎕↑(⍳n)/⍳n←⎕
```

Prompts for screen input for n and then for k. Index origin = 1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

Originally inspired by [GB's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149355/58974) and evolved to a port!

Takes `k` as the first input and `n` as the second.

```
õ1Vn)x
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9TFWbil4&input=MzEsMjQ=)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integers `U=k` & `V=n`. Generate an array of integers (`õ`) from `1` to `U` with a step of `V` negated (`n`) and reduce it by addition (`x`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 78 bytes

```
(({}<>)<{<>(({})<>){({}[()]<(({}))>)}{}({}[()])}{}<>{}>)({<({}[()])><>{}<>}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0OjutbGTtOm2sYOxNQEsquBdLSGZqwNWEDTTrO2uhYqBGLa2FXX2mlqVNvAxOxAIjZ2QCnN//9NFUwA)

I'm certain this can be done better, but it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 27 bytes

Anonymous function that takes `k` and `n` in that order. Creates a list of length `k` (third argument to `rep`) that is composed of `1` through `k` (first argument to `rep`), repeating each element `n` times (fourth argument to `rep`). Then takes the sum of that list.

`n` is 1-indexed and `k` is 0-indexed. Returns an error for `n<1`.

```r
pryr::f(sum(rep(1:k,,k,n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v6CossjKKk2juDRXoyi1QMPQKltHJ1snT1NT8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge, 27 Bytes

```
&::00p&:10p%+00g10g/1+*2/.@
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X83KysCgQM3K0KBAVdvAIN3QIF3fUFvLSF/P4f9/Q0MFIwA)

Takes k then n as input. Uses G B's answer as its mathematical basis.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
R÷ĊS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o8PYjXcH///83NPxvBAA)

Takes input in order `k`, `n`. Creates an array of ints from 1 to `k`, divides each by `n` and then rounds up, and sums.